# How to break after n characters with CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I need to break my table cell every 20 characters.

I found out, that there is a [`ch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) unit in CSS that allows me to limit my `max-width` like this:

```
td {
    max-width: 20ch;
}
```

Doing this limits the width of my cell, but does not break/wrap my strings. I tried to apply `word-wrap: break-word`, but this also didn't help me.

```
td {
    max-width: 20ch;
    word-wrap: break-word; /* does not work */
}
```

By the way: Most of my cells contain strings without spaces. Maybe this is necessary information.

**EDIT**

> Sorry for late edit, but after some investigation I found out that my `<table>` had the css attribute `white-space: nowrap;` by my table library. This caused my `word-wrap: break-word;` to loose effect.

Comment: Did you tried `word-wrap: break-all`? This will work to break your text and shift to 2nd line.

Comment: Please show the full HTML. It appears to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/uaon3mz7/

Comment: If I am correct max-width is for block elements only. For tables there are width but they'll grow to fit content if necessary. It may be better to combine width and word-wrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `monospace` font which renders all characters at the same width and `word-wrap:break-word`, but the `20ch` here in the snippet will result in 16 characters for some reason, so you'll need to find a setting that allows 20 characters, which here in my setup (Firefox on Mac) is `24ch`:

```css
td {
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  max-width: 24ch;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td>
    oiuhncoiuhOOSFwrevi987OINDVouhnweoriuhneaörlvjneriunONVWöoiunoiSAJunwrvwoiunVA
  </td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Unit `ch` doesn't work like that.

> Represents the width, or more precisely the advance measure, of the glyph "0" (zero, the Unicode character U+0030) in the element's font. [Source: mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

It means it will count the width of '0' (based on font) and multiplies it by value (20 times in your case). It means you can fit "0" 20 times into it. It won't break after any 20 characters. It is not possible to break word after 20 characters only by using `css` (as long as characters doesn't have same width). You need something *programmable* like *PHP* or *JavaScript* to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you for this useful hint, sir!

Answer (score 0):

```css
td {
  border-style: solid;
  max-width: 20ch;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td>
    a;lksjf;dsfasd;lakfjdskl;fadslkfjdsa;lkfdsfa;lkdsjfads;
  </td>
</table>
```

Is this what you were thinking?

Comment: Those are exactly the same properties the OP uses. You can style the `td` just fine. No need for an additional div. I assume there is a problem in OP's HTML rather than the CSS. Works just fine with `td`: https://jsfiddle.net/uaon3mz7/

Comment: Thanks didn't see that originally.